# Handling click events of a RecyclerView Item and the click events of buttons inside the item. Avoid listening to both at the same time

Tags: android, button, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have a recyclerview item with buttons in it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_margin="1dp">
 
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="1dp">
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id ="@+id/layLeft">
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDesc"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtCategory"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
                </LinearLayout>
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >
    
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_mark_done"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_set_as"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
    
    </FrameLayout>
```

A custom listener is created for handling the click events of RecyclerView items and for individual buttons.   When a button is clicked it is working fine with the click event listener.  But also the RecyclerView itemclick listener also is listened.  Which results in dual execution.

the listener is given below

```
    class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{

        private ClickListener clicklistener;
        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recycleView, final ClickListener clicklistener){

            this.clicklistener=clicklistener;
            gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(context,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child=recycleView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());

                    if(child!=null && clicklistener!=null){
                        clicklistener.onLongPress(recycleView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            View child=rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());

            if(child!=null && clicklistener!=null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
                clicklistener.launchIntent(rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) { }
    }
```

and for the buttons

```
 btnMarkDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    clickListener.onMarkDone( 0);
                }
            });

            btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    clickListener.onDeleteItem( 0);
                }
            });
```

Is there any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should try to avoid implementing RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener, insted do use the recycle view with adapter as follows and use TouchListener on recycleView Item click, code as follows -

```
public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    // your data variables

    public RecycleAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    // implement your click and touch listeners here

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new CustomViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
       //data binding code
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { 
        // return size;
    }


    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView btnMarkDone, btnMarkDone;

        public CustomViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            btnMarkDone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnMarkDone);
            btnMarkDone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnMarkDone);

            btnMarkDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // click listener here
                }
            });

            btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // click listener here
                }
            });

            itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    //implement touch listener action here
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

If you want action on recycle view scroll then user `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener`

Happy Coding !